# Prevent Page And Image Flickering

Tags: html, asp.net, css

The pages flicker on page load and the images flicker on postbacks. 
The following snippet did not work for me. Using Chrome. Any solutions.

MASTER PAGE:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv=”Page-Enter” content=”Alpha(opacity=100)”>  
   <%--<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.2)">--%>
   <%--<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.2)"> --%>
</head>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: I have put the images inside span with dimensions same as that of the image. Cant use div as the image has to be in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
```

Comment: Works good in IE but not in chrome. I need this for chrome :(

Comment: check if MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" of page attributes work

Comment: Yes thats working in chrome. I put this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true inside page_Load